# python relativedelta not working for months of 31

Tags: python-3.x, python-dateutil

I want to create quarter dates based on end date of previous quarter.
meaning that, for each quarter's end date i've to subtract 3 months to calculate start date of quarter and end date of previous quarter.

Problem is , when I do

```
ref_date - relativedelta(months=+3)
```

and ref_date is 30th june, it returns march 30th while it should return march 31st.
is there any solution to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with datetime.date objects.

You can check how many days are a in month of a year with [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) and use that as your date instead of just the negation result. When you got that figured out you have to create a new `datetime.date` because its attributes are not writable:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import calendar

ref_date = datetime.date(2022, 6, 30)
end_date = ref_date - relativedelta(months=3)
n_days = calendar.monthrange(end_date.year, end_date.month)[1]
end_date = datetime.date(end_date.year, end_date.month, n_days)
print(end_date)
```

Out:

```
2022-03-31
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
end_dt = ref_date - relativedelta(months=+3)
end_dt = end_dt + relativedelta(day=31)
```

ref:
[https://pynative.com/python-get-last-day-of-month/#:~:text=Day%20Of%20Month.-,Get%20The%20Last%20Day%20Of%20The%20Month%20Using%20dateutil,last%20day%20of%20the%20month](https://pynative.com/python-get-last-day-of-month/#:%7E:text=Day%20Of%20Month.-,Get%20The%20Last%20Day%20Of%20The%20Month%20Using%20dateutil,last%20day%20of%20the%20month).

Here is a test program for you, it will get and print the last day of each month of 2023.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

for m in range(1,12):
    input_dt = datetime(2023, m, 10)
    end_dt = input_dt + relativedelta(day=31)
    print(end_dt.date())
```

```
Output:
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
2023-03-31
2023-04-30
2023-05-31
2023-06-30
2023-07-31
2023-08-31
2023-09-30
2023-10-31
2023-11-30
```